# Замена для слова "троллить"

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, синонимы, заимствования, жаргон

Каким литературным словом или несколькими словами можно заменить появившееся несколько лет назад новое интернетовское словечко "**троллить**"? (от англ. *trolling* )

Столкнулся я как-то с небольшим спором, когда один интеллигентный человек сказал, что не желает, чтобы засоряли русский язык подобными новомодными заимствованными словами. На что ему ответили, что у этого слова "троллить" уже есть определённое особое значение. И предложили его заменить. Как-то никто и не нашёлся с ответом БЫСТРО. Долго над этим никто задумываться не стал, а мне вот вспомнилось.

Comment: А что оно значит?

Comment: Троллинг -- это такое неприятное явление в Интернете. Как-то даже не хочется его и описывать.

Знаете такое старое выражение "хам трамвайный"? :)
Появляется такое лицо в общественном транспорте, чаще всего женщина пожилого возраста, т.к. мужчине могут и, пардон, по морде дать. И начинает вокруг такой бабули скандал разрастаться, втягивая новых и новых участников.

Comment: Есть такие люди и в Интернете. Их прозвали "троллями". Тролль осознано, целенаправленно делает так, чтобы у участников интернетовского обсуждения появилась агрессия, злоба, негатив. И он получает от этого удовлетворение. Прошу прощения, что сам, в какой-то степени, написал сообщение с негативным содержанием.

Если своими словами, то так. А подробнее, если угодно, можно посмотреть в Википедии, статья "Троллинг". Но можно и не смотреть -- хорошего мало :-)

Comment: А как "интеллигентный человек" относится, например, к слову "гуглить"? Неужели надо говорить "искать с помощью интернет-поисковика"?  
Да, попутно: думаю, что "гуглить" можно и с помощью Яндекса. Почему же именно "гугл" стал основой для нового слова? Из-за технических характеристик, или чисто морфологических ("пояндексить" звучит более громоздко". не говоря уж о производных от Yahoo)

Comment: Я говорю: поищите в интернете. Или - поищите на Яндексе.

Comment: есть еще такое жаргонное слово - подкалывать. это в смысле провоцировать ради развлечения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По смыслу больше всего подходит слово "провокатор" ("провоцировать"). Но я не уверен, что оно исконно русское. Борцам с новомодными заимствованиями так же может не понравиться.

Comment: Согласен, провокатор пдходит больше других, но все равно это лишь очень отдаленный синоним "тролля". Тролль может ведь и не провоцировать, а просто тролить без всякой цели или не имея целью конкретное действие. Для провокатора это невозможно.

Comment: Цель у тролля есть всегда. Другое дело, что он может провоцировать не на какое-то конкретное действие, а просто для того, чтобы позабавиться.

Comment: Т.е. просто неуравновешенного, грубого человека (может, и со сдвигом) троллем считать нельзя? Если он "не ведает, что творит"...

Comment: @DocentI, хамство или там грубость - это вообще понятия, как говорится, параллельные троллингу.  Непересекающиеся.   
Троль это не характер, а производитель конкретных дейстия. Цель у него может и не быть (крнкретной), но действия объективно напралены на нарушение норамльной работы ресурса (социальной, просветительской, информационной и т.п.). А то и вовсе приводит к закрытию форума. Но самое старшное - по личному опыту - тролли, которые не осознают, что они тролли. Те, которые полагают, что это нормальный стиль обшения.

Comment: Спасибо. Слова "провоцировать", "провокатор" -- это очень близко. Если почитать какие-нибудь спорные **политические** темы в Интернете, то совсем подходит по смыслу. 

Но бывают обсуждения и не политического характера. Появляется там кто-то, и участников обсуждения дразнит, раздражает. Как старуха Шапокляк из мультфильма про крокодила Гену. :-)

Тут бы заменить каким-то выражением. Что-то вроде: **"провоцирует на что-то", "провоцирует что-то"**. А вот что (или на что)? Или тут ключевой вопрос -- **зачем?** Где-то близко хожу, но не могу сообразить.

Comment: Скорее всего провоцирует он исключительно ради забавы. Это если говорить про "зачем?". А если говорить о том, на что он провоцирует, то тут всё предельно ясно. Ему нужна какая-нибудь ошибка в рассуждениях другого участника, чтобы можно было за неё зацепиться. Лучше грубая и вызванная незнанием или непониманием, но в принципе подойдёт случайная и незначительная.

Comment: Очень кого-то напоминает...

Comment: Нет, нет, это не я!..

Comment: Конечно, это не Вы...

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых. "Тилигента" - на мыло. Это не борьба за чистоту языка, это типичный пуризм а-ля Шишков (или Хомяков). Помните "Хорошилише гредёт (грядёт?) по гульбищу из ристалища"? *Все хотел найти автора этой "пародии", но утонул в версиях.* Так вот, это как раз про таких дядей сказано.

И не могу не привести попавшийся вместе с Шишковым списочек:

*NB. Небольшое прибавление к списку истинно русских слов.

```
«Боксёр» - «дракодел»
«Джинсы» - «парусинки»
«Комета» (гр. «kometes» - «волосатый») – «волосатик»
«Конституция» - «постоянка»
«Прокурор» (лат. «procurare» - заботиться) – «судебный печальник»
«Психоанализ» - «душечлен»
«Саботаж» (фр. «saboteur» - «стучать башмаками» (сабо)) – «лаптебой»*
```

[Гвардей Цытыла - Возврат крови, или несколько фантазий на тему одной цитаты | srostki.ru](http://www.srostki.ru/news+index.storytopic+0+start+360+PHPSESSID+383884c57493b48754f3b776699f7036.htm)

Во-вторых. Троллинг - понятие пошире будет того, что тут приведено, трудно охватить одним словом. Но слово "тролль" в русском есть. Оно означает мифологического персонажа западноевропейской (англо-германской в основном) литературы. Не понимаю, почему не воспользоваться этим словом для обозначения того же явления, что и в языке-источнике.

Очень отдаленно это понятие можно передать как реализацию "комплекса Герострата". Или Нерона - это уж от типа тролля зависит: одному доставляет наслаждение результат, другому - сам процесс... Хотя разница небольшая.

Comment: >«Комета» (гр. «kometes» - «волосатый») – «волосатик»

Подумалось, а может быть слово "косматый" (в жен.р. "она космата" ) имеет какое-то дальнее родство с греч. «kometes» ?

И спасибо за интересный ответ.

Comment: Врял ди. Мне сейчас некогда в словари лезть, но появление "с" ничем не объяснимо.

Answer (score 4):

Есть архаичная замена "бретёрствовать", "бретёрство", "бретёр". Но называть так троллей, по моему слишком уж жирно. У бретёра хотя бы был риск, что придётся ответить за слова ранением или даже смертью.
А вообще смысла изобретать новое слово к явлению, которое появилось сравнительно недавно и определение себе нашло само, занятие довольно-таки бесперспективное.

Comment: Это Вы хорошо вспомнили... 
Но всё-таки "бретёр" - как я его понимаю - это не совсем тролль...  
Бретёр - фигура эпатажная, а среднестатистическому троллю это как-то не слишком важно. У троллинга есть цель помимо собственно троллинга. Он разваливает ресурс, на котором сидит, хотя сам может даже не осозновать этой цели или формулировать её как-то по-иному.

Comment: Цель троллинга - вызвать эмоциональную реакцию окружающих, а развал ресурса, лишь возможный побочный эффект. Есть куча сайтов, которые как раз и рассчитаны на то, что там сидят в основном тролли, например в ответы майл.ру разделы "политика" и "религия и вера".

Comment: Ну это вы слишком однобоко понимаете. Сколько троллей - столько и целей. Счет типов можно вести на десятки. 
Самый распространённый - это как раз сознательный тролль, который понимает, что его цель - сам ресурс. 
То, что вы представили как общую характеристику троллей, можно отнести к очень небольшому числу троллей с комплексом Герострата, которые таким образом этот комплекс и реализуют. Именно против таких троллей помогает бойкот, часто выдаваемый за панацею. Но увы, большинство троллей самодостаточны. Им наплевать на окружающих, они сами себе дают оценку. Это скорее уж комплекс Нерона.

Comment: Бретер — это вы им польстили. Мне кажется, тролли страдают "синдромом Герострата": сами создать ничего не способны, зато можно нагадить там, где уже создано. Или "Ах, Моська, знать она сильна..."  
И, честно говоря, даже больше чем тролли, меня возмущают ресурсы, которые этих троллей покрывают. Сталкивалась я с такими.

Comment: Нет, счёт типов троллей действительно может идти на десятки, и конечные цели конечно могут различаться, но цель вызвать эмоциональную реакцию на том  или ином ресурсе есть всегда. Без этой эмоциональной реакции, ни какой нужной троллю дискуссии не выйдет. Идеальный тролль - это тот, кто парой-тройкой постов добился живого и долгого обсуждения нужной ему темы.
Синдрома Герострата у них, или Нерона не знаю, тут надо каждого в отдельности смотреть. Скорее я бы назвал синдромом Воланда - создать дичайшую суматоху, и посмеиваясь над человеческими страстями, изредка подкидывать новые дровишки.

Comment: >но цель вызвать эмоциональную реакцию на том или ином ресурсе есть всегда    
  
А как вы тогда назовете тех форумчан, которые не соответствуют этому прокрустову определению?!

>Мне кажется, тролли страдают "синдромом Герострата":   
  
Далеко не все. Это частный случай, далеко не самый распростаненный. Я привол пример дрeгого комплекса: Нерона. Тому вообще люди были безразличны. Он сам процесс любил. И созерцать результаты.

Comment: Юзер, школота, белый рыцарь интернета и много других определений пользователей. Но троллями они станут только если будут иметь как минимум этот признак.

Comment: Да ну бросьте... Это все, согласен, не тролли, но я-то не о них.
Я про тех, кто именно троллит. Но с целью, допустим, нанести вред ресурсу. Кащенитов, например, Вы за троллей тоже не держите?

Comment: Ой, не льстите им! 90% троллей — это школота, которая хочет хоть как-то показать собственную значимость ("Ах, Моська, знать, она сильна..."), и по которой ремень плачет))))

Comment: Кащениты - это ныне практически вымершая разновидность троллинга, выделились они лишь из-за особой манеры троллить, а вызов эмоциональной реакции у собеседника(ов) у них виден в полной мере.

Школота и рада бы побыть троллем, но получается слишком толсто. Троллинг думаю в большей степени развлечение студентов.

Возвращаясь к сопоставлению бретёр-тролль, первый провоцирует негативную эмоциональную реакции оффлайн, и его могут вызвать на дуэль, второй онлайн, и кроме самой эмоции там нет ничего. Разрушить троллингом ресурс можно лишь при его зарождении, пока не сформировался стиль общения.

Answer (score 3):

Я называю таких существ "сетевые вампиры" по аналогии с "энергетическими вампирами". Они ведь тоже провоцируют людей на негатив и получают от этого удовольствие.

Comment: Спасибо. +1. Возможно на полноценную литературную замену и не потянет. Но определение отличное! Понравилось.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, вместо не очень понятного тролля можно вполне использовать такие русские слова, как зануда, хам, скандалист, брюзга и др.

Comment: Но ведь это далеко не синонимы. А _тролль_ объединяет все эти смыслы в нечто новое. Тем более, в вопросе идет речь о глаголе: как Вы назовете _действия_ тролля?

Comment: Хамить, занудствовать, скандалить, брюзжать

Comment: Причем все это одновременно...

Comment: Использовать-то можно. Но это лишь частичные синонимы. Помимо того, как уже сказали, что всё это нужно передать одновременно, одним словом, есть еще существенные моменты. У тролля всегда есть какая-то установка, он сознательный провокатор конфликта. В то время как у ваших персонажей её может и не быть (особенно у зануды или там боюзги - они ввобще в конфликте персонажи пассивные), это чаще всего - просто характер, от которого сам персонаж и страдает.  И самое главное Речь-то о глаголе. А значение глагола не совсем точно соответствует определению "то, что делает тролль".

Answer (score 1):

Сколько ни занимались переводом слова "троллинг" - бесполезно. Троллить - это троллить. Надо с этим смириться. Понятие достаточно емкое и в чем-то многозначное.

Можно только дать толкование, да и то с каким-то приближением.

Троллинг я бы определил как деятельность, направленную на высмеивание, унижение, компрометацию личности или мнения с использованием разного рода обычно неприемлемых методов, вывод пользователей из состояния эмоционального равновесия, разжигание ссор, скрытые провокации и вообще деятельность во вред ресурсу, не подпадающую под другие очевидные определения (флуд, спам, флейм).

Answer (score 0):

```
Но панталоны, фрак, жилет, 
Всех этих слов на русском нет; 
А вижу я, винюсь пред вами, 
Что уж и так мой бедный слог 
Пестреть гораздо б меньше мог 
Иноплеменными словами, 
Хоть и заглядывал я встарь 
В Академический словарь.
```

(А. С. Пушкин. Евгений Онегин)

Любой живой язык активно обменивается материалом. Вопрос не в явлении, а в мощности и обоснованности заимствований. Для "троллизма" адекватного эквивалента в русском "посконном" языке нет.

[[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus) ближе всех прочих к объективной реальности, хотя комплексы он приплел совершенно зря.

Comment: Явление называется не троллизм, а троллинг.

Comment: >хотя комплексы он приплел совершенно зря.  
  
-???

Comment: @Владислав -ай вэй, таки не учите мне за русский язык! Явление - *изм, действие - *инг (хотя и этот англицизм не нравится, мне, но "за неимением гербовой бумаги будем иметь дворника")

Comment: @behemothus - мотивы шире, часть может включать и помянутые комплексы, но мотивация значительно шире. И она (мотивация) очень разнообразна - затролливая МД-креакла, я заставляю оппонета раскрыться, что для прочих может иметь (при наличии у них хотя бы остаточного мозга) положительный воспитательный эффект, скажем.
Лев Натаныч Щаранский, скажем, ни разу не хам и не скандалист. А троллит душевно, с размахом

Comment: @behemothus - фразу про хорошилище лучше приводить в полной форме. Версия от Белинского «Хорошилище грядет из ристалища на позорище по гульбищу в мокроступах и с растопыркой» (в правильном ответе прокомментировать не могу)

Comment: >Версия от Белинского «Хорошилище грядет из ристалища на позорище по гульбищу в мокроступах и с растопыркой»  

Видел эту версию Только не у Белинского, а у гораздо более современных авторов. Если дадите ссылочку на Виссариона Григорьевича - буду весьма признателен.


>в правильном ответе прокомментировать не могу  
  
Это общея беда здешнего движка, не заморачивайтесь, привыкнете.

Comment: >но мотивация значительно шире.  
  
А я сказал, что **у**же? Где?

Answer (score 0):

Противление новомодным иностранным словам оправдано, думаю, тогда только, когда их используют в сфере нравственной, когда ими именуют какие-то поведенческие формы, особенно отрицательные. Другими словами, всё что связано с добром и злом педагогичнее называть словами с русским корнем. Пример, проститутка = блудница, а какой контраст! В первом слове порок скрыт, а во втором обличен. Хвалить, поощрять, наставлять русского лучше всего русским языком, языком которым говорили наши деды - чтобы была связь поколений, преемственность. Поэтому, думаю, в целях воспитания ума и благочестия у нашей молодежи нельзя потакать им, используя новомодные словечки, не имеющие в себе обличающего свойства и оценки со стороны нашей исконной ментальности, совести. А вот, неодушевленные предметы или нейтральные действия, не имеющие к спасению души (хоть бы и в этой жизни) никакого отношения, пожалуйста. И еще... Уж если у иностранцев хватает ума и словарного запаса давать новым явлениям имена из уже имеющихся слов, то и мы должны также поступать. Подстрекать, хамить и т.п. всё лучше, чем троллить. Важна, повторюсь, не точность, а наличие понятной нравственной оценки в слове.

Answer (score 0):

Не претендуя на буквальное соответствие, вариантом замены слова "троллить" может быть общеупотребительное русское слово *дразнить*.

Answer (score -1):

"Троллинг" или "троллить" можно заменить на слово "подстрекать". ПОДСТРЕКАТЬ, ПОДСТРЕКНУТЬ (подбивать, подбить, настропалить, подзуживать, подзудить, подначивать, подначить).

Comment: Ну если подстрекать, то тролль = подстрекатель?! Очень неточно.