# Гуглить с помощью Яндекса

Tags: заимствования, жаргон

В связи с вопросом о переводе слова [троллинг](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8540/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) меня заинтересовали и другие новые "интернет-слова". Например, практически каждый понимает, что значит *гуглить*, *погуглить* - "искать с помощью интернет-поисковика"

Лично я считаю, что "гуглить" можно и с помощью Яндекса. Почему же именно "гугл" стал основой для нового слова? Может, сыграли роль технические характеристики (распространенность этого поисковика, его больший возраст, возможности). Или причины чисто морфологические: "пояндексить", "рамблерить" звучит более громоздко.

А представьте себе русские производные от Yahoo ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, что это связано просто с удобством произношения и общей тенденцией к сокращению: например в этом же русле слово "*фотик*" - вместо "*фотоаппарат*", "*вебка*" - вместо "*веб камера*", "*велик*" - вместо "*велосипед*" и т.д.

К тому же слово "*гуглить*", таки удобнее чем "*яндексить*" - согласитесь?

Comment: Таки да. Я то же и говорю. С другой стороны, такие сокращения не всегда кажутся удачными, хотя, конечно, на вкус и цвет... Меня, например, раздражает "днюха" вместо "день рождения", а кто-то и "гуглить" ни за что не будет.  

И еще один аспект: гугл все-таки "основной" поисковик. Аналогичная история была со словами Xerox и Pampers, которые перешли из названий фирм в нарицательные (отксерить, ксерокопия, в разговорной речи можно сказать "памперс фирмы Libero").

Comment: По поводу слова **"ксерокс"**. Действительно, слова "отксерить", "ксерокопия" и т.п. говорят повсеместно. Но тут тоже есть борцы за правильность. :-)

Ксерокс -- копир, копировальная техника (это, скорее, в случае множественного числа, т.е. замена слову "ксероксы"). Не "ксерокопия", но "копия" :-). В рекламах фирм, торгующих оргтехникой, встречается что-то вроде: "Продаём принтеры, копиры..."

Comment: "Отксерить" -- сделать копию, скопировать. Конкретно слово "ксерить" мне тоже слегка не нравится. Точнее, я воспринимаю его как разговорное, неформальное. Как "велик" и "велосипед". В какой-то неформальной ситуации я и сам могу сказать: "Я смотаюсь на велике по делам и по дороге отксерю кое-что". :-) Но я всё-таки предпочитаю говорить: "Сделаю копию ...".

:-) Это я не спорю, если что... Рассуждаю о оттенках значений и восприятия новых слов.

Comment: Возражения по поводу ксерить совершенно другого порядка. "Ксерокс" - торговая марка, она же - название фирмы. В отношении же других копиров (а их сейчас подавляющее большингство) употребление весьма сомнительно.

Comment: Вчера шла мимо библиотеки - объявление: "Имеется ксерокс". Неужели Вы думаете, что они имели в виду конкретную фирму? И везде по городу: "Ксерокопия - n рублей".  А еще случайно увидела некую "юмористическую передачу", где ведущие "искали" Мадонну. Одна из них говорит: "Давайте загуглим ...". Уж они-то точно не думали о наличии нескольких поисковиков.

Comment: Да и словари уже давно зафиксировали значение у слова "ксерокопия" как копия, сделанная по определенной технологии.

Answer (score 0):

Часто слышу такие варианты (чаще чем "гуглить"): "искать в Интернете", "посмотреть в Интернете".

Comment: Формально говоря, это не одно и то же. Гугл - именно поисковик, а искать в интернете можно, например, с помощью последовательных гиперссылок. К тому же слово "гуглить" короче. И оно существует (в отличие от рамблерить)

Comment: Слово "гуглить" конечно же употребляется, не спорю. Но оно не всем нравится. И некоторые его просто не хотят употреблять. "Ненашенское"! :-)

Потом и поисковик "Гугл" -- не единственный. Есть такие пользователи, которые принципиально используют другой поисковик.
В общем, по моему скромному мнению, "гуглить" -- это искать с помощью Google.

Comment: Может быть и так. Боюсь, что для меня использование таких словечек имеет личную психологическую мотивировку. Например: "Не отстать от молодежи", ведь старость не за горами.

Comment: Может быть Вам тогда будет интересно почитать эту небольшую заметку  ["Компьютерный сленг. Часто используемые слова и выражения"][1]
Почти все эти слова действительно часто используются. Единственное, чтобы "наушники" называли "уши", **лично я** почти никогда не слышал (может кто-то другой меня поправит?). И я чаще слышал, что видеокарту называли "видяха", а не "видюха". 

  [1]: http://blog-pc.ru/kompyuternyj-sleng-chasto-ispolzuemye-slova-i-vyrazheniya.html

Comment: Для меня новостью был "буржуйнет".

Comment: Да, верно. Не обратил на него внимание. "Буржуйнет", пожалуй, не соответствует заголовку "ЧАСТО используемые слова и выражения".

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос, имхо, ни о чем.
Никогда не слышал, чтобы в отношении Яндекса или там Рамблера употреблялось бы "погуглить". Гуглить - искать с помощью гугла. До его появления "рамблить" или "яндексить" было вполне употребительны. насчет яху - не уверен, кажется было "йехить", "пойехить" или что-то подобное. А шутка про неблагозвучие Яху хотя и с бородой, но упирается в принципиальную невозможность сахранения конечной гласной. От кенгуру будет "кенгурить", а не "кенгуруить".

Comment: На этом форуме, когда задаем вопрос. выдается фраза: погуглить с помощью Яндекса

Comment: @behemothus, наверное, дело в том, что Вы программист. Для Вас гугл, яндекс, рамблер, ... - отчетливо различимые объекты. Ну, а для нас - простых юзеров - это все одно и то же.

Comment: Отнюдь. Просто гугл сейчас "съел" все остальные поисковики. А так-то простые пользователи их прекрасно различают. Ещё лет пять-десять назад можно было выбирать, скажем, между яндексом и рамблером (йэху уже тогда загибался) в ходу были и "рамблить" и "яндексить" - пользователи прекрасно ориентировались. Кроме того, были и существуют специализированные системы поиска (альтависта, например) в которых "конкретные" пользователи прекпасно ориентируются получше всех программеров.

Comment: Спасибо за хорошее мнение о нас, простых пользователях! Боюсь, что Вы не общались с моей мамой по этому поводу ;-))

Comment: Я сужу по тем, с кем общался. Правда это все более чем годичной давности, сейчас я если с кем и общаюсь, то все больше через интеренет.

Comment: У Вас хороший круг общения, только "страшно далеки Вы от народа" ;-))