# Тролли, мульты, клоны, флэймеры и флудеры

Tags: сетевой-жаргон

*"На большинстве форумов Рунета любой тематики львиная доля сообщений — это троллинг автора или несодержательные комментарии вместо реальных ответов."*
*Николай Чабановский, основатель, стратапер и админ "Сети Знаний".*

Вопроса, собственно, два.
***~1. Как Вы понимаеете фразу в "эпиграфе"?***
***~2. Кто они вообще такие, эти тролли, мульты, клоны, флэймеры и флудеры? В чем разница, какие еще есть сетевые мемы для разных категорий деструктивного элемента? ***

Спросил бы еще, всегда ли оная публика - это однозначное зло, но это уже, боюсь, тема для совсем другой "филологии".

Марк Из навел меня на мысль уточнить сентенцию об "однозначном зле".
Сетевые реализации "доктора Джекила" и "мистера Хайда" - мульты или клоны?

Про троллей кое-что у нас было интересного, тут: [Замена для слова "троллить"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8540/), но немного в другом разрезе.

*На всякий пожарный. Повод для темы связан с событиями на другом ресурсе и к данному прямого отношения не имеет.*

Comment: Я, к сожалению, ничем помочь не могу. Все эти слова узнала от Вас. Правда, потом еще у сына переспрашивала.  А про флаймера вообще первый раз слышу.

Comment: Я знаю только троллей, клонов и флудеров

Comment: Это сетевые жаргонизмы. Я и не рассчитывал, что все их знают. Но, возможно, интересно будет узнать.
Фл***э***ймера поправил. Опечатка. Ларf, спасибо.

Comment: >Сетевые реализации "доктора Джекила" и "мистера Хайда" - мульты или клоны?   
  
Много Вы таких встречали по жизни?

Comment: @behemothus, может целесообразней сделать исследование на данную тему и в рамках исследования уже задавать каждый вопрос отдельно, суммируя ответы в тексте исследования.

В рамках одного ответа разобрать все интересующие вас моменты довольно сложно, да и малопродуктивно, кто-то знает лучше одно, кто-то другое, а кому-то не захочется писать длинный текст отвечая на все вопросы.

Comment: Делайте, кто мешает?
Я разочаровался в исследованиях как в инструменте. 
По большому счету я вообще в формате данного ресурса разочаровался...
Но тут уж ничего не сделаешь.

Comment: Попробую таким образом поднять тему. @Artemix, да я имел в виду именно мульта-клона (мульт в том контексте мне казался удачнее, разницу можете посмотреть в этой теме)

Answer (score 4):

1) В русскоязычном сегменте интернета, большая часть сообщений это провокации и бессодержательные комментарии. Причём эта картина наблюдается независимо от тематики того или иного сайта.

2) Теперь по порядку термины. Сразу оговорюсь, определения свои, на основе посещения многих форумов и чтения определений с них, все представленные слова - это представители определённой модели поведения в интернете, поэтому, если не указано, что это персонаж, то я даю определение линии поведения, а не самому персонажу.

1. Троллинг (от английского "ловить на блесну") способ поведения в интернете, заключающийся в **намеренном** провоцировании людей на эмоциональную реакцию. Зачастую тролллей разделяют на толстых, или жирных и тонких. Условная граница между ними в том, что первые при провокации правила ресурса нарушают, а вторые нет, хотя в зависимости от сайта граница эта плавает, но прямое оскорбление - всегда троллинг толстый, а разжигание полемики без участия в ней - тонкий.
2. Мульт - от мультаккуант, дополнительный аккуант персонажа для получения какого-либо преимущества на ресурсе.
3. Клон - аккаунт, маскирующийся под другого персонажа. Например, [по ссылке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/1988/behemotus) клон автора вопроса. Если с этого аккаунта начать отвечать и давать комментарии, то они будут ассоциироваться с @behemothus'ом, а невнимательный читатель может даже решить, что это он и есть (акк создан только для примера и использоваться не будет). Как правило, подобные аккаунты создают чтобы опорочить участника сообщества или накрутить свой рейтинг за счёт известности данного лица.
4. Флэйм (чаще флейм) - спор ради спора. При этом зачастую идёт отход от самой темы дискуссии.
5. Флуд - сообщения без полезной информации, часто большие по объёму. Разновидностью флуда являются сообщения вне темы обсуждения и мультипостинг. Пример флуда:"*4444444444444444444444444454*"

Других деструктивных видов ещё много некоторые из них:
 1. Школота - школьники или им подобные пользователи, ничего не знающие, но считающие своё мнение единственно верным.
 2. Грамм-, или граммарнаци - человек придирающийся к орфографии и пунктуации, а не к сути сообщения.
 3. Боты - программа для спама, например на Ю-тюбе почти под каждым видео можно увидеть сообщение бота о том, что его уволили из сотовой компании и он знает секретный код.

Все эти персонажи могут быть для ресурса как злом так и благом, зависит от ресурса и тематики. Без лёгкого флуда и флейма вообще любой форум читать будет также интересно как энциклопедический словарь: полезно, но скучно.

Comment: Я тоже придираюсь к грамотности, потому что когда вижу пять ошибок в каждом слове, суть высказывания для меня уже ценности не представляет и вообще ускользает.

Comment: Это зависит от тематики форума. Одно дело исправлять ошибки на форуме русского языка, совсем другое на форуме, условно говоря, математики, или ресурса, где на русском обязаны общаться не только русскоязычные пользователи.

Comment: Не уловила разницы между мультом и клоном.

Comment: Ларf, да! См**о**трите в корень этой проблемы. Я тоже теряюсь, когда собеседник начинает разделять их, не объяснив принципа разделения.
Правда, проблема эта - далеко не главная во всей моем списке.

Comment: По-моему, мульты отличны, а клоны образуют тождества. То есть наоборот, чем у Марка Иза. Мульты — это шизофрения, а клоны — продукты сепуления, *инкарнации* в смысле тиражирования по исходному генетическому коду, только с разными никами-индексами. Сетевые реализации "доктора Джекила" и "мистера Хайда" — мульты. Кукловод мультов искуснее кукловода клонов; у первого — труппа с разными амплуа, у второго — дублёры, различающиеся только именами. 


Comment: >укловод мультов искуснее кукловода клонов; у первого — труппа с разными амплуа, у второго — дублёры, различающиеся только именами.  
  
Вы с Ириной меня почти убедили.  
  
>Например, по ссылке клон автора вопроса.  
  
Мысль понятна. Только вряд ли ***аллоним*** - клон. А хотя бы и мульт. Не знаю, как назвать такого перса, не сталкивался. 
А если по сути - такого быстро раскусят. Подделывать стиль почти невозможно. Как почерк или отпечатки пальцев. И останется просто перс с похожим ником.

Answer (score 2):

Мульты - это разные персонажи. Ведут себя по разному, маскируются под разных людей.

Клоны отличаются только ником, появляются там, где они разрешены и не скрывают, что они - клоны и чьи.

Как-то так.

Марка Иза тоже не очень поняла в этом. В остальном понимаю, в чем-то согласна.
Боты - люди, которые ведут себя как боты.

begemothus, абсолютного зла не бывает. Все зависит от того, как ситуацию понимают админы.

Comment: >begemothus, абсолютного зла не бывает. Все зависит от того, как ситуацию понимают админы.  
  
Угу. "Плюсик" - за это. 
А подробнее можете по всему вопросу?
Мне кстати, нравится Вше разделение мультов и клонов по признаку "образа жизни". Хотя кто из них - клон, а кто мульт - это еще надо крепко подумать...

Comment: Пояснил в ответе про клонов.

Answer (score 2):

- "1". Фразу из эпиграфа понимаю как выражение комплекса неполноценности админа. Либо жадности. Ибо для кого форум? Если для людей, так и дайте им развлекаться (или хотя бы сами не нойте).
- 2а. Желание (по)развлечься - основной мотив появления перечисленных мемов. Русские больше любят развлекаться и меньше боятся нарушать правила, более непосредственны. Никто не стремится специально и целенаправленно творить именно зло, это противно природе человека. Люди хотят получать удовольствие. А самое большое удовольствие для человека - потешить ЧСВ (тщеславие), возвыситься во мнении других (или хотя бы себя самого).

Возвыситься - это значит стать выше кого-то другого, хотя бы на полсантиметра; хотя бы на полсекунды почувствовать что ты кого-то уел (даже если через две секунды он докажет тебе, что ты облажался). Человек неосознанно ищет путей к самоутверждению, и проявляется это очень по-разному: кто-то уверенно пинает новичка за очевидную ошибку; кто-то выискивает у олдфагов опечатки; кто-то готов перерыть пол-интернета для доказательства своей правоты, провести целое исследование; кто-то от отчаяния уже готов на прямые оскорбления...

Тонко "вбросить" мотив для флейма - это уже настоящий профессионализм; думаю, таких людей во всём интернете можно пересчитать по пальцам. Потому что сообщество развивается, все опасные "холиварные" темы (типа "виндовс против линукс" или "нужно ли писать грамотно") давно известны постоянным участникам, и вы сразу получите реакцию "флейм детектед".

- 2б. Все остальные мотивы - надстройки над "основным инстинктом" (возможные благодаря ему). Например, на долгоживущих ресурсах обычно складывается "естественная защита" сообщества от неизвестности. Приходит новичок и задаёт банальный вопрос - стандартной реакцией будет не прямой ответ, а ирония, лёгкий троллинг. Если под видом новичка зашёл тролль, он ничего не получит. Если новичок несообразительный и обидчивый, он отвалится (ну, а зачем нам неинтересные новички?).
- "3". Нет постоянно-деструктивных или постоянно-созидательных участников. Скорее, есть роли, которые в разные моменты времени играет каждый из нас. Как раз недавно анализировал в этом плане один форум: http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/Три-самых-главных-пользователя.75245/

Ну, наверное, про кого-то можно сказать, что он "чаще деструктивый, чем созидательный". :-)

- "4". Если интересна развёрнутая классификация толщины троллей, почитайте Лурк (там все подробности выписаны тщательно до изжоги).

Answer (score 1):

***Марк Изу***.

> 1)...

Вопрос-то был о понимании сочетания "троллинг автора" (интересно было проанализировать как его понимает цитируемый). Впрочем - спасибо. Отчасти Вы и на него ответили неявным образом.

(в комментарии просто не лезет)

> Тролли... людей на эмоциональную реакцию

Никогда не слышал, чтобы во главу угла ставили эмоциональность ожидаемой  реакции. Т.е. не вообще, а именно так - эмоциональность как ***необходимое*** условие. Ну допустим (пока). А как тогда назвать тех, кто не ставит такой цели, но действует теми же методами? Просто с целью навредить ресурсу?  Ради удовольствия или по заданию конкурента? Просто термин хотя бы, пока можно без обсуждения. 
И еще. Из Вашего определения не ясно, можно ли назвать троллем того, кто "провоцирует" собеседника на ***положительную*** эмоциональную реакцию. Ну, например, рассыпается в комплиментах собеседнику в надежде получить *плюс в репутацию* (аналог местных "очков уважения")?

> Мульты ... клоны

Вот это интересно. Это Ваше восприятие или есть "узаконенное" разделение по такому признаку? Вики не предлагать, там слишком много субъективизма. Я бы согласился с  подобной трактовкой, не будь знакомым с повсеместной практикой, полностью исключающей подобное определение мульта.

Специально для Вас дублирую свой дополнительный вопрос.

Сетевые реализации "доктора Джекила" и "мистера Хайда" - мульты или клоны?

> Других деструктивных видов

Эти из другой "папки". То, что Вы написали, больше напоминает эмоциональные оскорбления. Этак вы сюда еще и чайников запишете в деструктивный элемент. Я все-таки тяготею, что термины надо отделять от ***ярлыков***. Ни боты (ботоводы тогда уж), ни школота, ни трололо, ни все прочие новые и старые *сетевые мемы* подобного типа не подходят под мои критерии "списка". Они либо не вредят, либо не осознают, либо не нарушают - и т.д. А ботоводы - это вообще этакий подвид хакеров; ну или инструмент в их руках - в зависимости от авторстава ботвары (софта). Ни разу не слышал, чтобы мем ***выключи бота*** использовали в прямом значении - на форумах по крайней мере.

Можно и их всех обсудить, но нельзя ж объять необъятного.
К своему сптску я бы мог добавить пожалуй только мультипостера, но для меня это подвид флудера. Ваше определение это, кстати, исключает.

//---------

Пока понял только то, что понимание совсем не однозначно. Впрочем, именно в этом и хотел убедиться.

***Fuchoin Kazuki***

Да, одна из движущих сил тролля - *синдром Герострата*. 
Но поскольку я смотрю на троллинг гораздо шире, то и это считаю лишь частным случаем, далеко не главным. С таким же успехом можно найти у тролля "синдром Нерона", близкое знакомство с *Маней Грандиозовой* или *Ларри Лузером*, а то и вовсе *Эдипов комплекс*. Последнее, признаться, мое личное наблюдение, если интересно и в тему - расскажу.

(Это для Вас лично) Я почитал интервью expert'a, при всей его нахрапистости, ангажированности и неоднозначности мне стало понятнее, какой он видит стратегию развития ресурса. Вы знаете, *под этим углом* не уверен, что именно на СЗ вся эта публика (включая троллей) - однозначное зло... Но не смею навязывать.

Comment: Тролль пишет провокационные сообщения, чтобы вызвать эмоциональную реакцию (нет реакции - нет и желания ответить, а следовательно и возможности для споров). Какие цели помимо вызвать эмоциональную реакцию преследует тот или иной тролль нам всё равно установить вряд ли получится.

Мультов и клонов как правило не разделяют, но там где мне разделение попадалось (1-2 проекта)делили именно так. Клон там был фейком известного персонажа или группы, мульт - дополнительный акк.

Моё определение Флуда (сообщения без полезной информации) вполне вмещает в себя и мультипостинг и сообщение не по теме.

Answer (score 0):

А по поводу того, что всегда ли это однозначное зло, я, как человек, немало пострадавший от троллей, скажу однозначное: "Да!"
И понять их никогда не смогу. Что хорошо в том, чтобы обгадить хорошее произведение, умное высказывание или чье-то мнение? Это что, синдром Герострата?

Comment: Не все так просто. Худа без добра не бывает.
Но я не конкретно про троллей. Про деструктивный элемент вообще.
Я боялся, что обсуждение уйдет очень далеко от тематики форума, но с ващего позволение продолжу эту тему, когда буду писать свой ответ.

Comment: Fuchoin Kazuki, Вас троллить милое дело: Вы ведетесь на любую провокацию. Трудно быть модератором с таким темпераментом.

Comment: Вы часом не полагаете, что это я - тролль и провокатор?
Если да, то готов обсудить. Вполне корректно. С Вас - только примеры и объяснения. 
По сути. Я не думаю, что действующему модератору стоит в открытую сообщать о таких вещах. Во всяком случае я не имел в виду подобное, открывая данную тему.